# Xamarin iOS App rejected - presentViewController non public API

Tags: ios, xamarin

My app was rejected in the Apple Store for the following reason:

Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

presentViewController:

I'm using Xamarin iOS and MvvmCross 4.1.0. Reviewing the app the only place I use this API is for share a web link, image, text etc. This is how I use it:

```
// Share functionality
        btnShare.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            //_openInWindow = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl (NSUrl.FromFilename (DocumentUrl));
            _openInWindow = new UIActivityViewController (new NSObject [] { NSUrl.FromFilename (DocumentUrl) }, null);
            //_openInWindow.PresentOpenInMenu (new CGRect (0, 260, 320, 320), this.View, false);
            PresentViewController (_openInWindow, true, null);
        };
```

I've done a little bit of research and sometimes this error arises when the API call is deprecated, but I think this is not the case.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any more details from the Apple review?

Comment: No, just possible causes of the issue, like deprecated APIs, possible methods with the same name of the non public API, etc. but I don't think this could be applied to presentViewController.

Comment: What version of `Xamarin.iOS` is being used to build that project?

Comment: Xamarin.iOS
Version: 9.8.2.22 (Xamarin Studio Community)

Comment: I saw this answer to a similar question, it looks like it shows how to find which of your binaries are calling the non-public API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39782178/3757150