# Issue Apple Store: non-public API "setMaximumLength, MaximumLength

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having problems with the publication of an App on 'Apple Store; Apple has refused to publish the App because it found references to non-public APIs, specifically: "setMaximumLength :, MaximumLength". Unfortunately, analyzing the source code, I was not able to find the calls to these Apis. How can I solve this problem?

--- APPLE MESSAGE ---

2. 5 PERFORMANCE: SOFTWARE REQUIREMENTS
   Performance - 2.5.1

Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

setMaximumLength:, maximumLength

The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

--- END OF THE MESSAGE ---

Versione XCode 8.0

Versione Xamarin.Forms2.3.2.127

Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.2

Xamarin.iOS 10

Comment: If you're not doing it directly, then what 3rd party libraries are you using? Maybe one of them is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apple's XCode command line tools, notably `strings` or `otool` to look inside binaries and see which may be calling that private API.

Found in this post: 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3838251?tstart=0:

> "Additionally, one or more of the above-mentioned APIs may reside in a static library included with your application. If you do not have access to the library's source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov" will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined methods. These techniques can help you narrow down where the problematic code resides."